# How to set an alarm to fire properly at fixed time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I have this code

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 22);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        firstTime += 30*1000;
        long a=c.getTimeInMillis();

        // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                c.getTimeInMillis(), 1*60*60*1000, sender);
```

It is not executed at **23:22h**

What I am doing wrong? I noticed firstTime and c.getTimeInMillis() differs a lot in size and length. When I use firstTime, so when set to 30 seconds, the alarm is executed well.

Comment: I've seen that in this example: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#kZ0MkhnKNzw/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/CheckUpdateService.java&q=setRepeating%20package:http://apps-for-android%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` flag, but you are using a Calendar object.  These two things don't go together.

You need to use [AlarmManager.RTC](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC) or `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` if you are specifying the alarm time using a Calendar or Date object (milliseconds since 1970).

You use `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` when you are specifying the alarm time via `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` (milliseconds since the phone booted).

Answer (score 8):

I had success with the following code, if you only want to set the alarm for the next occurance of hh:mm

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 19);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    //check if we want to wake up tomorrow
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cal.getTimeInMillis()){
        cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis()+ 24*60*60*1000);// Okay, then tomorrow ...
    }
```

Comment: This is exact answer which fire alarm next day if time was gone

Answer (score 4):

To get the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now, use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

to get the current time, and then

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis()+30000, sender);
```

Edit:

I think the problem is the ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP.  This tells the AlarmManager that the time you are giving it is based on time since system startup.  This is fine for 30 seconds from now, but if you want it to be based on real time you should use  RTC, or RTC_WAKEUP.  See [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC) for full explanation of those types.

Comment: I need to go off at specific time 23:22h. I already have a working solution to go off in 30 seconds, that is working well.