# can AlarmManager(alarm.setRepeating) work in case of phone restart - Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I came in to scenario that I want to trigger service on specific time.

What I Know is...
I need use `AlarmManager`, and I found this question in hear, [Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time). Now, I am able to start service on specific time.

Now question I have is... I need 24H interval to start service. now What happens if the phone restart. **Is it going to start service again?**

How can I make this thing happen? 
Please help me with this

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.. It wont.. You need to set it again when phone Boots .. something like [this](http://www.androidenea.com/2009/09/starting-android-service-after-boot.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to register a BroadcastReceiver that can receive the BOOT_COMPLETED message so it receives a message when the phone reboots...

Read this article!

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/