# How to fire off alarm after every 30mins

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

**-** Ya i know this question has been asked here before and their links are:

[Android: Alarm to be play every 30 minutes and it start from 12:30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039593/android-alarm-to-be-play-every-30-minutes-and-it-start-from-1230)

[Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time)

[Android: Alarm to be play every 30 minutes and it start from 12:30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039593/android-alarm-to-be-play-every-30-minutes-and-it-start-from-1230/10039699#10039699)

**-** Now in my case i want **my application to be installed at any hour of the day**, and then it **start ringing every thirty minutes**, but **NOT from the time of its installation but in the order of the below example...**

**Eg:**

`-->` I installed the App at 11:15 am.

`-->` Now as clock of my mobile struck 11:30am it should start ringing, then again at 12:00pm it should ring, then at 12:30pm and so on.....

**-** Now in my case `setRepeating` of `AlarmManager` is not firing, or even if firing its not working....

**-** I tried using `Threads within Service`, that worked, but made the whole process to heavy, almost non-functionable.

Here is my code...........

**TestService.java**

//Its the Service that keeps running.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestService extends Service {
    /*
     * public static SharedPreferences myPrefs; public static
     * SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
     */
    private PendingIntent pendingIntentFri;
    private boolean ENABLE;
    private boolean isDone = true;
    Intent myIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Toast.makeText(this, "Test.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Test.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        System.out
                .println("I reached TEST SERVICE.........................................................");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Test.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        /*
         * Intent myIntent = new Intent(TestService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
         * pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(TestService.this, 0,
         * myIntent, 0);
         */

        // myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        ENABLE = ClockActivity.myPrefs.getBoolean("enable", false);
        System.out.println("ALARM SERVICE RECREATED WITH THE VALUE :::::: "
                + ENABLE);

        System.out
                .println("FROM TESTSERVICE..........................................:"
                        + ENABLE);

        if (ENABLE) {

            System.out
                    .println("FROM IF ENABLED BLOCK TESTSERVICE..........................................:"
                            + ENABLE);
            startAlarm();
        } else {

            System.out.println("FROM ELSE ITS NOT ENABLED: " + ENABLE);
        }
    }

    public void startAlarm() {
        // AlarmManager alarmManager =
        // (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        myIntent = new Intent(TestService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
        // pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(SettingsActivity.this, 0,
        // myIntent, 0);

        // Working for the Perfect Time...
        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());// set the current
                                                            // time and date for
                                                            // this calendar
        final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        // cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        // cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);

        Intent myIntentFri = new Intent(TestService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
        pendingIntentFri = PendingIntent.getService(TestService.this, 0,
                myIntentFri, 0);
        final AlarmManager alarmManagerFri = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
        // pendingIntent2);

        alarmManagerFri.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), (30 * 60) * 1000, pendingIntentFri);// for
                                                                            // 30
                                                                            // minutes

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

}
```

**MyAlarmService.java**

// The file that holds the logic

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.sax.EndTextElementListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
    public static SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
    private boolean SILENCE;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        System.out
                .println("I AM IN  MYALARMSERVICE..............................................");
        Calendar ct = Calendar.getInstance();
        ct.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int Hour = ct.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int Minute = ct.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        System.out.println("Hour and Minute in Calender is: " + Hour + ":"
                + Minute);

        myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SILENCE = myPrefs.getBoolean("silence", false);

        int sHour = myPrefs.getInt("start_hour", 01);
        int sMinute = myPrefs.getInt("start_minute", 00);
        int eHour = myPrefs.getInt("end_hour", 02);
        int eMinute = myPrefs.getInt("end_minute", 00);

        System.out.println("======== SILENCE PERIOD ==========");
        System.out.println("The Start Time is: " + sHour + ":" + sMinute);
        System.out.println("The END Time is: " + eHour + ":" + eMinute);
        System.out.println("==================================");

        Calendar currentTime = new GregorianCalendar();

        // currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        // currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
        // currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
        // currentTime.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
        // currentTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);

        Calendar start_time = new GregorianCalendar();
        start_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
        start_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
        // start_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
        // start_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
        // start_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);

        Calendar end_time = new GregorianCalendar();
        end_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, eHour);
        end_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, eMinute);

        // if((sHour>eHour)){ // if the Start == PM and End == AM
        // System.out.println("Day is increase. . . .");
        // end_time.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        // // end_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
        // // end_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
        // // end_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
        // }else{ // if the Start == PM and End == AM
        //
        // System.out.println("Day is same. . . .");
        //
        // // end_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
        // // end_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
        // // end_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
        // }

        System.out
                .println("=============== CURRENT TIME DETAIL ===============");
        System.out.println("CURRENT TIME:   " + currentTime.getTime());
        System.out
                .println("CURRENT DATE:   " + currentTime.getTime().getDate());
        System.out.println("CURRENT HOUR:   "
                + currentTime.getTime().getHours());
        System.out
                .println("===================================================");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("=============== START TIME DETAIL ===============");
        System.out.println("START DATE:   " + start_time.getTime().getDate());
        System.out.println("START TIME:   " + start_time.getTime());
        System.out.println("START HOUR:   " + start_time.getTime().getHours());
        System.out
                .println("===================================================");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("=============== END TIME DETAIL ===============");
        System.out.println("END TIME:   " + end_time.getTime());
        System.out.println("END DATE:   " + end_time.getTime().getDate());
        System.out.println("END HOUR:   " + end_time.getTime().getHours());
        System.out
                .println("===================================================");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println(start_time.getTimeInMillis() + " < "
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + " && "
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + " > "
                + end_time.getTimeInMillis());

        if (!SILENCE) {
            System.out.println("SILENCE in if is :" + SILENCE);
            fireAlarm(Hour, Minute);
        } else {

            System.out.println("SILENCE in else is: " + SILENCE);

            if (sHour > eHour) { // FOR START == PM and END == AM

                System.out.println("FOR start=PM AND end=AM");

                if (((((start_time.getTimeInMillis() <= System
                        .currentTimeMillis())) || ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= (end_time
                        .getTimeInMillis()) + ((3 * 60) * 1000)))))) {
                    System.out.println("You are in Silent mode");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ship's Clock is Silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    fireAlarm(Hour, Minute);
                }
            } else { // FOR START == AM/PM and END == AM/PM

                System.out.println("FOR start=AM/PM AND end=AM/PM");

                if (((((start_time.getTimeInMillis() <= System
                        .currentTimeMillis())) && ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= (end_time
                        .getTimeInMillis()) + ((3 * 60) * 1000)))))) {
                    System.out.println("You are in Silent mode");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ship's Clock is Silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    fireAlarm(Hour, Minute);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm(int Hour, int Minute) {

        // if(Hour>12){
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // "Please Set the More the 12 Hour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // }

        // 12:30
        if ((Hour == 12) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("ONE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
        }
        // 01:00
        if ((Hour == 1) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("TWO Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.two_bells);
        }
        // 01:30
        if ((Hour == 1) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("THREE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.three_bells);
        }
        // 02:00
        if ((Hour == 2) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("FOUR Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.four_bells);
        }
        // 02:30
        if ((Hour == 2) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("FIVE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.five_bells);
        }
        // 03:00
        if ((Hour == 3) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("SIX Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.six_bells);
        }
        // 03:30
        if ((Hour == 3) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("SEVEN Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.seven_bells);
        }
        // 04:00
        if ((Hour == 4) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("EIGHT Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
        // 04:30
        if ((Hour == 4) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("ONE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
        }
        // 05:00
        if ((Hour == 5) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("TWO Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.two_bells);
        }
        // 05:30
        if ((Hour == 5) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("THREE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.three_bells);
        }
        // 06:00
        if ((Hour == 6) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("FOUR Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.four_bells);
        }
        // 06:30
        if ((Hour == 6) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("FIVE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.five_bells);
        }
        // 07:00
        if ((Hour == 7) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("SIX Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.six_bells);
        }
        // 07:30
        if ((Hour == 7) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("SEVEN Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.seven_bells);
        }
        // 08:00
        if ((Hour == 8) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("EIGHT Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
        // 08:30
        if ((Hour == 8) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("ONE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
        }
        // 09:00
        if ((Hour == 9) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("TWO Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.two_bells);
        }
        // 09:30
        if ((Hour == 9) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("THREE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.three_bells);
        }
        // 10:00
        if ((Hour == 10) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("FOUR Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.four_bells);
        }
        // 10:30
        if ((Hour == 10) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("FIVE Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.five_bells);
        }
        // 11:00
        if ((Hour == 11) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("SIX Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.six_bells);
        }
        // 11:30
        if ((Hour == 11) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("SEVEN Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.seven_bells);
        }
        // 12:00
        if ((Hour == 12) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Eight Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
        // 00:00
        if ((Hour == 00) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Eight Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
        // 00:30
        if ((Hour == 00) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("One Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
        }
        // //////////////////// FOR 24 HOUR

        // 13:00
        if ((Hour == 13) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Two Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.two_bells);
        }
        // 13:30
        if ((Hour == 13) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Three Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.three_bells);
        }
        // 14:00
        if ((Hour == 14) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Four Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.four_bells);
        }
        // 14:30
        if ((Hour == 14) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Five Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.five_bells);
        }
        // 15:00
        if ((Hour == 15) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Six Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.six_bells);
        }
        // 15:30
        if ((Hour == 15) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Seven Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.seven_bells);
        }
        // 16:00
        if ((Hour == 16) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Eight Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
        // 16:30
        if ((Hour == 16) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("One Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
        }
        // 17:00
        if ((Hour == 17) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Two Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.two_bells);
        }
        // 17:30
        if ((Hour == 17) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Three Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.three_bells);
        }
        // 18:00
        if ((Hour == 18) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Four Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.four_bells);
        }
        // 18:30
        if ((Hour == 18) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Five Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.five_bells);
        }
        // 19:00
        if ((Hour == 19) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Six Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.six_bells);
        }
        // 19:30
        if ((Hour == 19) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Seven Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.seven_bells);
        }
        // 20:00
        if ((Hour == 20) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Eight Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
        // 20:30
        if ((Hour == 20) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("One Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
        }
        // 21:00
        if ((Hour == 21) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("two Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.two_bells);
        }
        // 21:30
        if ((Hour == 21) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Three Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.three_bells);
        }
        // 22:00
        if ((Hour == 22) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Four Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.four_bells);
        }
        // 22:30
        if ((Hour == 22) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Five Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.five_bells);
        }
        // 23:00
        if ((Hour == 23) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Six Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.six_bells);
        }
        // 23:30
        if ((Hour == 23) && (Minute == 30)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Seven Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.seven_bells);
        }
        // 24:00
        if ((Hour == 24) && (Minute == 00)) {
            System.out.println("The Time is: " + Hour + " : " + Minute);
            System.out.println("Eight Bell");
            playSound(R.raw.eight_bells);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void playSound(int resources) {

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resources);
        mp.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, this is way too long, snip out the repetitive stuff and leave only what is strictly necessary to ask the question!

Comment: Thereof redundancy that you can simplify with some smarter logic handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is pretty broken:

```
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE); <-- This sets the day of the month to 5!
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH); <-- This sets the month to 2 (March)!
```

What are you trying to do here?

Why don't you just create a Calendar with the parameters you want, like this:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // Current date and time
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
// Round minutes up to next multiple of 30
int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
if (minutes < 30) {
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
} else {
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1); // Next hour (will roll the day/month/year over if needed)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to take the current time and add 30 mins in ms:

```
30 mins (30 mins to ms = 60s * 1000ms * 30) = 1800000 ms

long Offset = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1800000;
```

And you should be printing what time the alarm is set for **DURING** debugging to ensure it is set to go off at the right time.

use the getTime() method on the Calendar Instance and then print it in local time.