# Android calendar intent

Tags: android, calendar

I am making an alarm app. This app calls an intent when the alarm is active (active by the calender). When the alarm or calendar goes off, I want to call an activity, which is `hello.class`. This class is mentioned in the pending intent which gets called by the calender. When the calender gets called and the pending intent should be dealt with, NOTHING at all happens. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

My code is below: The line labeled "ABC" by a comment is where the `hello.class` is mentioned

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, Hello.class); // ABC


pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Perhaps this can be of help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your intent because the activity will be launched outside of the context of an existing activity.

The documentation says so.

Just add

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

below `Intent myIntent = new Intent...`

And change `PendingIntent.getService(...)` to `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could you give me some sample code on where to locate it, sorry I'm still just a beginner.