# Using Alarmmanager to start and stop a service at specific time everyday

Tags: java, android, time, alarmmanager

How to start and end a function using Alarm-manager everyday at specific time

For eg StartTime : 07:00 End Time :15:00

```
 Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
 cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

 Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
 cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);
 cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
 cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
 cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
 cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pendingIntent );
```

Answer (score 0):

Set one Alarm for starting at 7:00 and one for stopping at 15:00, using Intent-Extras to specify the correct action (starting or stopping).

Also, compare [Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time?rq=1)