# How to start a service at a specific time

Tags: android, multithreading, service, timing

Am creating an application that fetch data from webservice. I have been `while(true)` and sleeping the loop at a specific milliseconds.. i had like to make the service action(fetching data from webservice) to always start at a specific time.. instead on being on always and pausing by `Thread.sleep(milli)`... Thanks
this is what have been using

```
while(true)
{
///pullDataFromWebservice();
Thread.sleep(600000);
}
```

Comment: this link maybe can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Alarm API.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) It is way safer than having a sleep & poll service.

Why?

Because Android is very likely to **reclaim such a long running services when resources turn low**, resulting
in your delayed logic never being called!

An example for activating a callback in 1 hour from now:

```
private PendingIntent pIntent;

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyDelayedReceiver.class);  <------- the receiver to be activated
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60*60*1000, pIntent);  <---------- activation interval
```

Comment: Very helpful. really saved me time. the 'PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)' will it be sending a broadcast??

Comment: the pending intent wraps that intent that will be used by the alarm manager to wake up your receiver at due time

Comment: i meant, other context have to receive the broadcast sent by The AlarmManager?? i can also use 'PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0)' to start the service instead of sending a broadcast ??

Comment: I have successfully scheduled ,but Consider a situation,if the app is cleared by task manager,does the schedule still works?

Answer (score 0):

Try using AlarmManager - A bit battery eater though

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

//RTC_WAKEUP to enable this alarm even in switched off mode.
```