# How set repeat alarm for an specific interval

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I need to invoke a broadcast receiver using alarm intent since it will invoke the my broadcast receiver for a particular interval. for that I am using alarm manager and pending intent.

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmSetter.class);
            boolean alarmLive = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)!=null);
            if (alarmLive)
                Log.e("","---alarm up");
            else {
                PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

I need to set this alarm which will start when create and invoke at morning 4 AM

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3058837/4191629

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time)