# How to Call a java class after 10 minutes of non-interacting with notification bar?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a notification at particular time using alarm Manager and notification manager, i gave  user three action in notification bar "Snooze", "Cancel", "Take". Here is the situation i want to resend the notification after 10 min of this notification again and again till the user presses these above buttons.
Can any body help and provide a decent logic to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would schedule a repeating Alarm and only cancel it on a non "Snooze" action. See the setRepeating method of AlarmManager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

to schedule a new alarm after the initial one goes off, you'll want to start a service with the AlarmManager which can then handle the Snooze action for you.

[Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time)

Comment: Yes i can setRepeat but the problem i am facing is that i am already using setRepeat for repeating for regular days.

Comment: I was thinking when user presses any button i will again set new alarm for after some time(say user presses snooze after 10 min ) so i will using alarmmanager.set function for this