# Logic for call method each day after 24 one at a time in Java

Tags: java, android

Logic in mainMethod:

```
String todaydate=DateUtils.todayDateinToString();
if ( !todaydate.equals(localdate.get())) {
    long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(currentMillis >= appProperties.nextCallMillis.get() ) {
        localdate.set(currentMillis + 86400000);
         callmethod();
    }
    appProperties.barCodeCallDate.set(DateUtils.todayDateinToString());
}
else{
    appProperties.nextCallMillis.clear();
}
```

DateUtils.java

```
public static  String todayDateinToString() {
    String today = null;
    try {
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        // Display a date in day, month, year format
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        today = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("Today : " + today);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return today;
}
```

i wrote this code to execute each day once after 24 hour interval.

Actual: its executing each day only once.

Expected: it should execute each day after 24 hour. For example i call method today at 11 am then it shouldn't call tomorrow before 11 am. It should call after 11 am. If I try to call day after tomorrow it should call before 11 am because that difference for next call is 24 hour.

please suggest me i am storing two  date and nextCallMillis in locally .

Comment: are you doing this in android?

Comment: yes in android i have to do it @KaranMer

Comment: you can use alarmmanager for it, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time

Comment: test case we dont have to use Alarm Manager @KaranMer

Comment: You're making it quite complex with the millisecond usage etc. Just take the date you executed it last time, and calculate for example total seconds between the dates. No need for different handling on what day it is etc. If it's over 24 hours, then it's ok.

Comment: @JamesZ can you edit and tell me how we can do this