# How to call a service to notify when certain time has arrived in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, service, notifications

I am working on an application that sends some dates and times to service and I need the service to do a notification message when that those times and dates have arrived.thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this topic will help You:

[Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time)

All You need to do is schedule an `AlarmManager` to a specific date, and then build a notification with a `BroadcastReciever`