# Can I setup the Alarm Clock!

Tags: android, alarm

This is a good one, i am trying to pass a intent to the alarm clock to set it off.  Can someone please help me out if this can be done..  it sounds like something that can be done but cant find it anyway

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer this [How to set an alarm to fire properly at fixed time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992882/how-to-set-an-alarm-to-fire-properly-at-fixed-time)

Comment: this does not do it.  I need to fire all the alarm clock, this does not fire off a alarm that would make a sound!

Comment: how on mother earth this is the accepted answer ? and do you even read the question before posting an answer ?