# Android: Get system time and schedule a task

Tags: java, android, time, alarmmanager

I have been trying to figure out how to get the current time in android and I would like to figure how to run a segment of code when the clock hits a certain time. Ultimately what I am trying to do is when the clock is 9:30 pm. Do something or run a piece of code. I have never dealt with time before on android or java.

Comment: Does your application will be running as service or you need to start @ 9:30?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can get the current time in Android such as

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Regarding running code at a certain time, check out [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) which allows you to schedule a run for your application.

Also, check out [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Answer (score 0):

There's some things you need to consider when using `AlarmManager` especially when your device is asleep (acquire a lock, and keep it until your task is completed). I suggest you read [that](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/wakeful.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

get the current system time as below:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and set task for future time as below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, GPSTrackerService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//every 2 min
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),timeSlice, pintent);
```

for more description refer below link:

[How to set an alarm to fire properly at fixed time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992882/how-to-set-an-alarm-to-fire-properly-at-fixed-time)

Comment: How would I apply this, I just want to check if the time is 9:30pm or not?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992882/how-to-set-an-alarm-to-fire-properly-at-fixed-time